# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

Title : ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, None, None, 3]

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import os
img_width, img_height = 28,28 
input_depth = 1 
train_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Shreya\Desktop\Project\basedata\training'
validation_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Shreya\Desktop\Project\basedata\validation'
testing1_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Shreya\Desktop\Project\basedata\testing\tomato'
testing2_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Shreya\Desktop\Project\basedata\testing\not tomato'
epochs = 2 
batch_size = 5
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      train_data_dir,
      color_mode='grayscale',
      target_size=(img_width,img_height),
      batch_size=batch_size,
      class_mode='categorical')
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      validation_data_dir,
      color_mode='grayscale',
      target_size=(img_width,img_height),
      batch_size=batch_size,
      class_mode='categorical')
testing1_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      testing1_data_dir,
      color_mode='grayscale',
      target_size=(img_width,img_height),
      batch_size=batch_size,
      class_mode='categorical')
testing2_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      testing2_data_dir,
      color_mode='grayscale',
      target_size=(img_width,img_height),
      batch_size=batch_size,
      class_mode='categorical')
 NUMB_FILTER_L1 = 20
 NUMB_FILTER_L2 = 20
 NUMB_FILTER_L3 = 20
 NUMB_NODE_FC_LAYER = 10


 if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
     input_shape_val = (input_depth, img_width, img_height)
 else:
     input_shape_val = (img_width, img_height, input_depth)


 model = Sequential()


 model.add(Conv2D(NUMB_FILTER_L1, (5, 5), 
             input_shape=input_shape_val, 
             padding='same', name='input_tensor'))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))


 model.add(Conv2D(NUMB_FILTER_L2, (5, 5), padding='same'))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))


 model.add(Conv2D(NUMB_FILTER_L3, (5, 5), padding='same'))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))


 model.add(Flatten())


 model.add(Dense(NUMB_NODE_FC_LAYER, activation='relu'))


 model.add(Dense(train_generator.num_classes, 
            activation='softmax', name='output_tensor'))


 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])



 model.summary()

 model.fit(
     train_generator,
     steps_per_epoch=np.floor(train_generator.n/batch_size),
     epochs=23,
     validation_data=validation_generator,
     validation_steps=np.floor(validation_generator.n / batch_size))

 train_generator.class_indices

 for i in os.listdir(testing1_data_dir):
     img = image.load_img(testing1_data_dir + '//' + i, target_size=(200,200))
     plt.imshow(img)
     plt.show()

     X = image.img_to_array(img)
     X = np.expand_dims(X,axis=0)
     images = np.vstack([X])

     val = model.predict(image)
     if val==1:
         print("Tomato")
     else:
         print("Not Tomato")
```

When the last part was run, The following error was displayed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BOKy.png)

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, None, None, 3]

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with this line

```
model.add(Conv2D(NUMB_FILTER_L1, (5, 5), 
             input_shape=input_shape_val, 
             padding='same', name='input_tensor'))
```

If your dataset is of RGB images, input_shape should have 3 channels
something like

```
input_shape =(img_width, img_height, 3)
```

If in case Grayscale image, use channel value as 1