# Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Traceback:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 1, 300, 300)

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import os
import theano
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

img_rows, img_cols = 300, 300
img_channels = 1

path1 = "./images"
path2 = "./resize"

listing = os.listdir(path1)
listing2 = list(listing)
num_samples=size(listing)

for i in range(len(listing)):
    if "jpg" in listing[i]:
        im = Image.open(path1 + '/' + listing[i])   
        img = im.resize((img_rows,img_cols))
        gray = img.convert('L')
        gray.save(path2 +'/' +  listing[i], "JPEG")
    elif "txt" in listing[i]:
        listing2.remove(listing[i])

imlist = os.listdir(path2)

im1 = array(Image.open(path2 + '/'+ imlist[0]))
m,n = im1.shape[0:2]
imnbr = len(imlist)

immatrix = array([array(Image.open(path2 + '/'+ im2)).flatten()
              for im2 in imlist],'f')
                
label=np.ones((num_samples,),dtype = int)
label[0:1260]=0
label[1260:2716]=1
label[2716:]=2
data,Label = shuffle(immatrix,label, random_state=2)
train_data = [data,Label]

img=immatrix[167].reshape(img_rows,img_cols)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
print (train_data[0].shape)
print (train_data[1].shape)


batch_size = 32
classes = 3
epochs = 20

filters = 32
pool = 2
conv = 3

(X, y) = (train_data[0],train_data[1])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)


X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')


Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, classes)

i = 256
plt.imshow(X_train[i, 0], interpolation='nearest')
print("label : ", Y_train[i,:])


model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(filters, conv, conv, padding = 'valid',
                        input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1),
                        data_format = "channels_last"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Convolution2D(filters, conv, conv, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Convolution2D(filters, conv, conv, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))


model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (pool, pool), strides = pool, padding = "valid"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs,
              verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

I've tried various approaches such as [ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064694/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-sequential-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expected), but I still face the same error. May I ask if anyone has a solution to this?

I know that the problem lies with the line

```
model.add(Convolution2D(filters, conv, conv, padding = 'valid',
                        input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1),
                        data_format = "channels_last"))
```

But I'm not too sure how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Your image shape is `(1,300,300)` but your code expects `(300,300,1)`, reformat one or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a fairly descriptive/accurate error message. The input shape you are giving it is (batch, img_rows, img_cols, 1), yet it is clearly seeing images to be shape (batch, 1, 300, 300). So it seems like you just have one dimension setup wrong. Just do something like

```
train_data = tf.transpose(train_data, [0, 2, 3, 1])
```

And you should be set

Comment: Or as the other commenter mentioned, you could change your input shape. But given that you are doing convolutions, it is important you understand which dimension corresponds to the convolutional kernel.

Comment: hey so right now my train data looks like this :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11IjPFBxBOUoNzSIO1Yh4HZ55zpCkERFz/view?usp=sharing

and so when i try to do 

`train_data = [data,Label]`
`train_data = tf.transpose(train_data, [0, 2, 3, 1])`

it just gives me this error:
**ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.**

any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Oh I see that you made your training data a list with the labels. If you just do the transpose to the X_train and X_test, that is what you want. Let me know if it doesn't work and I can take a look at the data on a colab file

Comment: Did that end up helping?